# Alertmanager Unique id

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am working with alertmanager.

I want to check the details Alertmanager is saving at the backend for each alerts.

Does Alertmanager creates an unique key for alerts received?

I want to know is there any work around to fetch it?

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Comment: i m using an api to get all the details.@Ji

Comment: this /api/v1/alerts

Answer (score 0):

The API provides a fingerprint that can be used as a ID:

```
curl prometheus:9093/api/v1/alerts | jq

{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "labels": {
        "alertname": "x",
        "instance": "x",
        "job": "x",
        "kubernetes_namespace": "x",
        "kubernetes_service_name": "x"
      },
      "annotations": {
        "summary": "Probe for service x failed"
      },
      "startsAt": "2018-07-25T09:43:09.34190371Z",
      "endsAt": "2018-07-25T09:48:59.2920459Z",
      "generatorURL": "https://x",
      "status": {
        "state": "active",
        "silencedBy": [],
        "inhibitedBy": []
      },
      "receivers": [
        "x"
      ],
      "fingerprint": "dd19ae3d4e06ac55"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: jq is just for pretty printing the JSON output, you can go without it

Comment: which version of alertmanager is it? Because if i m trying i am not getting it curl -s -N http://localhost:9094/api/v1/alerts

Comment: Version: 0.12.0

Comment: same we are using .But still not receving

Comment: What do you receive as response? errors / status code / any output / timeout?

Comment: {"status":"success","data":[{"labels":x},"startsAt":"2018-06-28T12:52:53.960064026Z","endsAt":"2018-07-25T11:38:53.7044952Z",,"status":{"state":"active","silencedBy":[],"inhibitedBy":[]}}

Comment: i m not getting the receivers and fingerprint part

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce it. I guess that you can also use a combination of labels and start time to generate a unique ID

Comment: newer builds of Alertmanager now send this fingerprint to webhooks as part of the payload

Comment: I DO NOT believe the `fingerprint` field is unique! I don't even think the combination of `fingerprint`, `alertName`, and `startsAt` is unique either! Please assist me with this question if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066569/is-the-fingerprint-field-in-alertmanager-unique