# Is the fingerprint field in Alertmanager unique?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, fingerprinting

I am developing a dashboard, which receives all Alertmanager readings and processes them. I looked for a unique field in the request payload to create a unique external alert id in my database. The request payload looks something like this:

```
{
  "status": "firing",
  "labels": {
    "alertname": "",
    "app": "",
    "cluster": "",
    "deployed_location": "",
    "instance": "",
    "job": "",
    "kubernetes_namespace": "",
    "kubernetes_pod_name": "",
    "pod_template_hash": "",
    "release": "",
    "replica": "",
    "severity": ""
  },
  "annotations": {
    "description": "",
    "summary": ""
  },
  "startsAt": "",
  "endsAt": "",
  "generatorURL": "",
  "fingerprint": ""
}
```

I first used the `generatorURL` field, but then realized it many different alerts have the same value for `generatorURL`. I have been trying `fingerprint`, and the situation is much better. However, I am having instances where 2 to 15 alerts have the same `fingerprint`.

I am wondering:

1. Is there really no unique field in Alertmanager requests?
2. It is the nature of Alertmanager logic (or that of my alerts) that a number of alerts are created with the same `fingerprint` and I should just deal with it and handle it on my side, i.e. not create an incident in my DB if the given `fingerprint` is already used. I also worry that if I set `unique=True` on my alert model, some new alerts that have the same fingerprint will be missed...

Comment: At this point, I am pretty sure the fingerprint field is NOT unique. What's more interesting, though, is that I'm using `fingerprint`, `alertName`, and `startsAt` to generate a unique id, and I am still getting duplicate alerts.

Answer (score 9):

If you jump to the `alert.Fingerprint()` definition, like [this one](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/a8ed0d58509d0251adcb159552b9ab098e206f1f/store/store_test.go#L32), can find the impl of [fingerprint](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/a8ed0d58509d0251adcb159552b9ab098e206f1f/vendor/github.com/prometheus/common/model/signature.go#L56)

So, `alert.Fingerprint()` is just unique for `labels`

```golang
// labelSetToFingerprint works exactly as LabelsToSignature but takes a LabelSet as
// parameter (rather than a label map) and returns a Fingerprint.
func labelSetToFingerprint(ls LabelSet) Fingerprint {
    if len(ls) == 0 {
        return Fingerprint(emptyLabelSignature)
    }

    labelNames := make(LabelNames, 0, len(ls))
    for labelName := range ls {
        labelNames = append(labelNames, labelName)
    }
    sort.Sort(labelNames)

    sum := hashNew()
    for _, labelName := range labelNames {
        sum = hashAdd(sum, string(labelName))
        sum = hashAddByte(sum, SeparatorByte)
        sum = hashAdd(sum, string(ls[labelName]))
        sum = hashAddByte(sum, SeparatorByte)
    }
    return Fingerprint(sum)
}
```